# How to recognize mouse location on map in the picture box?

Tags: vb.net

I have a country map in a picture box with provincial divisions. I can fill each province on mouse over by calling following floodfill function on my pictureBox MouseMove event:

```
Private Structure BITMAPINFOHEADER
    Dim biSize As Integer
    Dim biWidth As Integer
    Dim biHeight As Integer
    Dim biPlanes As Short
    Dim biBitCount As Short
    Dim biCompression As Integer
    Dim biSizeImage As Integer
    Dim biXPelsPerMeter As Integer
    Dim biYPelsPerMeter As Integer
    Dim biClrUsed As Integer
    Dim biClrImportant As Integer
End Structure

''' <summary>
''' API declarations
''' </summary>
''' <param name="hdc"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function CreateDIBSection Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByRef pBitmapInfo As BITMAPINFOHEADER, ByVal un As Integer, ByRef lplpVoid As IntPtr, ByVal handle As Integer, ByVal dw As Integer) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestDC As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer, ByVal hSrcDC As IntPtr, ByVal xSrc As Integer, ByVal ySrc As Integer, ByVal dwRop As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function ExtFloodFill Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal crColor As Integer, ByVal wFillType As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function CreateSolidBrush Lib "gdi32" (ByVal crColor As Integer) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Function GdiFlush Lib "gdi32" Alias "GdiFlush" () As Integer
Private Const SRCCOPY = &HCC0020

Public Sub FloodFill(ByRef mbmp As Bitmap, ByVal col As Color, ByVal Pt As Point)
    If mbmp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim srcDC As IntPtr = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero)
    Dim dstDC As IntPtr = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero)
    Dim dstBMI As BITMAPINFOHEADER
    With dstBMI
        .biBitCount = 24
        .biHeight = mbmp.Height
        .biSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(dstBMI)
        .biWidth = mbmp.Width
        .biPlanes = 1
    End With
    Dim dstBits As IntPtr
    Dim mbmpGetHbitmap As IntPtr = mbmp.GetHbitmap
    'Select the bitmap into an HDC
    Dim Obmp As IntPtr = SelectObject(srcDC, mbmpGetHbitmap)
    'Create a DIB
    Dim dstBMP As IntPtr = CreateDIBSection(dstDC, dstBMI, 0, dstBits, 0, 0)
    Dim Obmp2 As IntPtr = SelectObject(dstDC, dstBMP)
    'Place our bitmap in the DIB
    BitBlt(dstDC, 0, 0, mbmp.Width, mbmp.Height, srcDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
    GdiFlush()

    'Create a brush to use to FloodFill
    Dim mBrush As IntPtr = CreateSolidBrush(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(col))
    Dim hmm As IntPtr = SelectObject(dstDC, mBrush)
    'Label5.Text = mBrush

    'Fill with color
    ExtFloodFill(dstDC, Pt.X, Pt.Y, GetPixel(dstDC, Pt.X, Pt.Y), 1)
    'Get the bitmap back with the Filled Color
    mbmp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(dstBMP)

    'Go berserk clearing memory
    'ExtFloodFill has a bad reputation for gobbling up memory
    'if you dont clean up properly
    DeleteObject(mBrush)
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(dstDC, mBrush))
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(dstDC, dstBMP))
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(srcDC, mbmpGetHbitmap))
    DeleteObject(hmm)
    DeleteObject(dstBits)
    DeleteObject(Obmp2)
    DeleteObject(Obmp)
    DeleteObject(dstBMP)
    DeleteDC(dstDC)
    DeleteDC(srcDC)
    mbmpGetHbitmap = Nothing
    hmm = Nothing
    dstBits = Nothing
    Obmp2 = Nothing
    Obmp = Nothing
    dstBMP = Nothing
    dstDC = Nothing
    srcDC = Nothing
    dstBMI = Nothing

End Sub
```

the only thing I need is to recognize floodfilled province on mouse over. any suggestion?

Comment: If I can get floodfilled province AREA this may be usefull

Answer (score 0):

If you know the map coordinates you could do bounds checking on a defined list of rectangles.

i.e. a class which has a name as string and a rectangle

so washington might be (0,0,100,100)
and new york might be (100,40,100,100)

then just look through your list of objects and bounds check them
return the "name" of the area to the user

if that is what you were trying to achieve.

p.s. i'm not sure why you're using alot of "classic" blitting / GDI code where the .NET framework system.drawing namespace could be much nicer for you....

```
dim b as New Bitmap(Width, Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
dim g as graphics = graphics.fromimage(b)
g.Clear(Color.White)
g.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile("test.jpg"), New Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100))
PictureBox1.image = b
```

Comment: by the way the bitmap class has a getpixel method too which returns a color

Comment: thanks for your responses. I've tested .net framwork functions and I didn't found them faster than GDI codes. if I can get floodfilled AREA it may be usefull

Comment: the only thing I need is to recognize floodfilled province on mouse over. any suggestion?